# Cross-platform open-source asychronous HTTP and DB with C#

Tags: c#, database, http, asynchronous, mono

Does anyone know of a good resource for open-source libraries for asynchronous C# (or native stuff to the language). I'm interested in anything on this topic, but I'm specifically looking for stuff pertaining to HTTP and DB calls. Maybe an event-driven framework with plugs for HTTP and DB?

Unfortunately I can't use a non-C# solution or anything that does not work on mono, unless it is planned to run on mono soon.

Comment: Unfortunately the Windows Workflow (which is the gist of what you're asking for) is very far from being implemented under Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/Workflow , in pre-alpha state.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly this does. I know C# already supports asynchronous events, and I believe you can get some non-blocking HTTP library working with it... What does Workflow do? Why do I need it?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you're trying to do. You can run anything async or multithreaded using something as simple as delegates, but if you need messaging, workflow, queuing, or something else... that'll be determined by your requirements. Maybe some background on the problem you're trying to solve would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTTP, it kinda depends on whether you're talking about client or server.  Assuming client, you could just use the *Async methods in WebClient

http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T:System.Net.WebClient/*

For DB, the sqlcommand (or similar) class exposes BeginExecute* methods for async calls

http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand/*

Comment: I've chosen this as an answer, but manly to close the question. I found Remus Rusanu's comment the most applicable for scoping out the project even if yours was more useful if I had to use C#. The bottom line is what I'm seeking is totally covered in Workflow which isn't yet stable on mono.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to use some kind of queue system. There are lots of queue engines. MSMQueue is the "standard" Microsoft solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Linxter Internet Service Bus system?  You can find some details at http://www.linxter.com and some sample apps that show how to perform database transactions distributed over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite generic, both HTTP, DB and asynchronous could mean a lot of different things, depending on the requirements:

On [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/webserver) you can find a more standards compliant HTTP server implementation which is event driven, compatible with Mono and has been used by others successfully.

There are a number of Asp.Net providers, as well as [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html)

For Linq to Sql, your best option will probably be to use [DbLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/) although DbLinq is being included in the Mono namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should check [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/). If it runs on mono it offers you a good framework for asynchronous calls (based on messaging).
It doesn't offer DB or HTTP connectivity by default, but this should be fairly easy to integrate.